# Are There Countries Beside The USA That Have Partisan Elected Officials Run Elections?

Tags: election, parties, comparative-politics

In the United States, the predominant election administrators are county clerks elected as partisan elected officials, and state level secretaries of state, who are elected as partisan elected officials.

Moreover, in the event of a disputed federal election in the United States, partisan elected officials in Congress are the ultimate arbiters of those disputes.

Are there any other countries which vest election administration primarily in partisan elected officials, and if so, which ones?

Comment: Would it be better to have it run by partisan people who are not elected? I think it would be very hard to remove the politics out of running elections and no matter what you will end up with partisan people in charge of them.

Comment: @JoeW The usual method is to have elections either administered by civil servants selected on the basis of a merit system of hiring who are insulated from elected officials with, for example, protections from being fired without cause, or to have it administered by civil servants selected by a board that is designed to have equitable partisan balance so that bipartisan/multipartisan agreement is necessary to appoint the official who then appoints other election administrators and makes key decisions. Elected officials, unlike partisan appointees, administer elections in which they participate.

Comment: Sure but that doesn't mean you won't be getting partisans into those positions, just look at the current postmaster general in the US and how it became a very political position and the current office holder appears to be wanting to destroy the post office system.

Comment: @JoeW No formal institutional tool is perfect in the absence of a strong culture of non-corruption. But it is far easier for a non-partisan civil service appointee to act in a non-partisan manner when administering election laws than for a partisan elected official participating in a particular election who has an intense incentive to act in a partisan manner to do so, which is why almost no other country has such a system.

Comment: My point is do you want people who can be held accountable by elections or those who can't and would need the bureaucracy to deal with it when corruption is found.

Comment: The theory of elections in the US is not supposed to be accountability in the sense discussed here. It is supposed to be "two party" accountability. That is, two sets of avid partisans openly watching the other to be able to catch any shenanigans. This is also, to some extent, how my country Canada does things. Poll watchers are invited and required from each party to the election.

Comment: @Dan Partisan vote watchers are one thing, but that only affected the margins, it doesn't impact global election administration decisions.

Comment: The US seems to have an unusually high degree of "it shouldn't be done if it's not an elected position".  For example, medical experts are pushed back against because they're not elected.  On the other hand, US judges are often elected.  What seems to be missed is that positions requiring high degree of skills aren't *enabled* by a popularity contest.  And in the case of elections, it seems like a *really* bad idea to hand the reigns over to a party.  Last getting elected doesn't mean no corruption: https://www.nytimes.com/2021/05/17/us/politics/joel-greenberg-guilty-plea-matt-gaetz.html

Comment: In England and Wales, the ceremonial administrators of elections are [returning officers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Returning_officer) who are often partisan elected figures (e.g. councillors for a particular party serving as mayor or local authority chairperson), but in practice they delegate most of the functionality to a council officer who is a non-partisan civil servant.

Comment: By definition, if the person who is running the election is allowed to vote, they will have partisan views. We are talking about people who have opionions.

Answer (score 7):

One example is the [People's Republic of China.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_China)  Essentially all aspects of elections are run by the Chinese Communist Party (CCP).

Elections are held at local levels to pick the representatives of the local People's Congress. These bodies then elect mayors, governors, and other similar office holders. And they also elect the reps to go to the next higer level of People's Congress. This heirarchy spans the entire country up to the national People's Congress.

The CCP tightly controls the nomination and election process at every level. This extends to, among other things, not allowing specific individuals to run for or hold office. There is also tight control over speech and the media such that messages deemed unacceptable are strongly suppressed.

Comment: I had been thinking about countries with meaningful multi-candidate elections, but I don't disagree that you are correct.

Comment: America's proudest moment: "Our elections are run like China's".